# Background image with JS React and Semantic-ui

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui

Hei
Trying to get my page to display an image that is behind the text and icons.
Here is what I have currently:

```
import React from 'react';
import SamplePicture from '../../images/sample-picture.jpg';

class Front extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="ui segment">
                <img className="ui floated image" src={SamplePicture} />
                <p>
                    This is a front page that will have an image in the background 
                    <br />
                    Sampletext
                </p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Front;
```

It displays the image but the text gets rendered below.
Basicly I want to create text that gets rendered on top of the image.

First time asking a question here so maybe there is some information that I should have shared, but haven't. Anyway, be harsh, tell me what is wrong about the code, the question.

Comment: Why not using `background-image` instead of `img` tag?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this using flexbox:

```
<div className="ui segment">
  <div className="ui medium image">
    <div
      className="ui active center"
      style={{
        display: 'flex',
        position: 'absolute',
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        zIndex: 1,
      }}>
      <div className="content">Sampletext</div>
    </div>
    <img
      src="https://via.placeholder.com/410x210"
      className="ui floated image"
      alt="alt"
    />
  </div>
</div>
```

This solution uses `flexbox` to center the text over the image.

I've used `via.placeholder.com` as an image source to make it easy to demo, but you can change it to your image's src.

---

If the text isn't exactly centered, either change your  container to a smaller size (from medium to small for example) or choose a bigger (wider) image.